# No se ejecuta la aplicación

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, app

No sé que he tocado y/o escrito, pero ahora la app no se ejecuta.
Según Android Studio no hay ningún error, pero la aplicación se detiene antes de que pueda abrirse.

Os dejo el enlace a una carpeta de [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14bo8rOOBP05PJ-F9JMJinRqxk052Rll-?usp=sharing) con los archivos de la app para que me podáis ayudar.

Comment: El código relevante a la pregunta va aquí por favor edita

Comment: Si tienes dudas lee [ask]

Comment: Hola BetaM, el problema es que según Android Studio no hay ningún error y por lo tanto no sé qué parte del código es errónea. Si me puedes dar algun consejo para saberlo estaré muy agradecido. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Si la ejecutas en modo debug te puede ayudar a encontrar el problema.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Si miras los logs, verás la siguiente exception:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ID does not reference a View inside this Activity
        at android.app.Activity.requireViewById(Activity.java:3375)
        at androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat.requireViewById(ActivityCompat.java:363)
        at androidx.navigation.Navigation.findNavController(Navigation.java:58)
        at androidx.navigation.ActivityKt.findNavController(Activity.kt:30)
        at com.treballrecercammr.okgarden.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:30)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Y se está quejando en la línea:

```
val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
```

Al comentarlo y sus referencias posteriores, se ejecuta:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo tanto revisa cómo montar el Navigation.